# Media Recorder example app crashes - why so?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-mediarecorder

I tried to run an example to record with the camera in Android, but it crash and the error showed in the console is not giving me a valide error to help me understand what happening.
I'll show you the code, so if anyone can help me to understand why the application crash.
in activity_main.xml there are just 2 button that call function start and stop Recording.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File audiofile = null;
    static final String TAG = "MediaRecording";
    Button startButton,stopButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        isStoragePermissionGranted();
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    }

    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
        } else {

            Log.v(TAG,"Permission is revoked");
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        }
    }
    else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        Log.v(TAG,"Permission is granted");
    }
}
    public void startRecording(View view) throws IOException {
        startButton.setEnabled(false);
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        //Creating file  
        File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try {
            audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "external storage access error");
            return;
        }
        //Creating MediaRecorder and specifying audio source, output format, encoder & output format  
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    public void stopRecording(View view) {
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
        //stopping recorder  
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        //after stopping the recorder, create the sound file and add it to media library.  
        addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
    }

    protected void addRecordingToMediaLibrary() {
        //creating content values of size 4  
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "audio" + audiofile.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (current / 1000));
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/3gpp");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, audiofile.getAbsolutePath());

        //creating content resolver and storing it in the external content uri  
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri base = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Uri newUri = contentResolver.insert(base, values);

        //sending broadcast message to scan the media file so that it can be available  
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newUri));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Added File " + newUri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I added the errors in Logcat, to help you

````
07-25 17:51:16.244 20019-20019/com.example.decoding E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.decoding, PID: 20019
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4740)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4735)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder._setAudioSource(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.java:488)
        at com.example.decoding.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:46)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4735) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
    ```
````

Comment: If app crashes you should have stack trace in Logcat pane in the Android Studio. Please try to find it and add to the question.

Comment: i don't know the correct way to add error in a stackoverflow question, so i decided to use ``````, u can see it after the code.

Comment: Which Android version and device are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by asking for permission programmatically even for Mic, here is the code :

```
public void isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        // Else ask for permission
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]
                    { Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, 0);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open up your android manifest and add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

For future reference, this is the relevant part of your logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder._setAudioSource(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.java:488)
    at com.example.decoding.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:46)
```

Comment: no sir, my manifest already had 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />